# Within a loop, is there a way to have the name of a variable change/depend on the value of the current index?

Tags: java, for-loop

For example (we are told we want to go up to 'X'):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i; i <= X; i++)
  {
    System.out.println("Enter the value for value " + i)'
    int valuei = scan.nextInt();
  }
```

So instead of constantly reasssining a value to the one variable 'valuei', 
 our program would create X number of integer variables as well as assigning them the corresponding user input as values.

'value1' gets the value the user had input as an answer at index 1

'value2' gets the value the user had input as an answer at index 2

...

'valuei' gets the value the user inputs as an answer at index i

If not possible, what would be the most efficient way to accomplish the above?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for arrays?

Comment: `int[] values = new int[x]; values[i]= scan.nextInt();`

Comment: Hm, possible. I'm probably overthinking it..

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are wanting to use arrays

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int arr [] = new int [X];
for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
  {
    System.out.println("Enter the value for value " + i)'
    arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
  }
```

Comment: Yep, did not check what the OP wrote

Comment: So @Scary Wombat another question here. I asked my original question due to wanting to figure out a way to correspond integer values to the letters A through Z which I have being used as variables. Let's say I'm giving A, B, C, and D as my letters. I now want the user to assign/correspond an integer value to them. Why I asked my question was because I thought if I could have a loop where I can create variables 'valueAssociatedWithLetterA', 'ValueAssociatedWithB', etc.. then later in my program I can easily reference the value corresponding to a particular letter.

Comment: But with arrays, to refer to an element, I need to refer to it's index. And I can't do "arr[C]" or something to refer to the value associated with letter C. Is there a way to name the value of an array at a particular index so that we can refer to it without using the arr[index]? So that's kind of where my question was coming from, would I have to have numerous lines of code that say ` int valueA = arr[0] ` `int valueB = arr[1] `?  Hopefully that made sense, thanks again.

Comment: @Boolean_functions Sounds like you want to create a custom object to hold both the letter and number information.

Comment: @Boolean_functions maybe you should consider using a `HashMap<String, Integer>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are just reading it then you can just need to read the value from user and it should be `i<x` because index starts at `0`.

```
     `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i < x; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the value for value " + i);
            int valuei = scan.nextInt();
        }`
```

If you want to read that in an array :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the value for value " + i);
        arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array

```
int []valuei = new int[X];

valuei [0] gets first input.

valuei [1] gets second input.
```

....

valuei [X-1] gets Xth input.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int []valuei = new int[X];

for (int i=0; i < X; i++)
{
 System.out.println("Enter the value for value " + i);
 valuei[i]=scan.nextInt();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Arrays.

> [An *array* is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

For example:

```
int[] value = new int[X];
for (int i=0; i < X; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the value for value " + i);
    value[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Also note how loop changed to `int i=0; i < X; i++`